# How are SOAP and Service related together and how many ways to create a Service in TIBCO BW?

Tags: web-services, soap, tibco

Iam often confused with these two terms SOAP and Web Services.
There is a service pallete in BW and we can create a service using this pallete.
Is there another way to create Service?
And are SOAP and Services related to each other in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP palette is the "legacy" web service palette. It is still used (especially for consuming) because it is simple and "to-the-point".

The "Service" palette is the new generation of web service definition (but not new enough to allow REST service within BW5). One of the main goal of the service palette was a better integration in the broader "ActiveMatrix" TIBCO ecosystem. Code copy-pasted from designer could be used in Service Grid, and the binding options allowed the use SOAP/HTTP, SOAP/JMS, REST and WS-addressing and WS-Security "easily" (the quotes are very important here). They called that "BW5 Code inside Service Grid" component "BWSE".

FYI : BW6 came and took all good features from BWSE and BW5, to present a better product.